# Can I sync an existing database using a .dmp file?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g-r2

I have two oracle databases (production and lab). When I created the lab database I imported a .dmp file from production to copy the data. Now that the database has been running for a while the data is out of sync and I'd like to import again. What's the easiest way to do this?

I tried using imp again but it shows errors now since the tables are already there. I could delete the data files and re import I suppose.

Edit: This is what I've tried:

```
$ imp user/password file=MyExportFile.dmp

following statement failed because the object already exists:
CREATE TABLE ...
...
Import terminated successfully with warnings.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace everything then the safest method is to drop all schemas  and import it again using imp

`drop user schema_name cascade`

You can also try ignore=y parameter in conventional import utility which will ignore the error when the object with the same name exists, which is  called TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION in data pump.

```
imp user/password@servicename file=abc.dmp IGNORE=y
```

In the case of data pump method, use table_exists_action parameter to skip the existing object as below:

```
impdp sys/password@servicename dumpfile=abc.dmp logfile=imp_skip.log tables=abc table_exists_action=truncate
```

Comment: This appears to be the answer I'm looking for. I used the imp method. Deleting the user with cascade option wiped out all the old data, ensuring that nothing would be left over that I didn't want. Then re-adding the user is very easy through the Enterprise Manager. Much easier than deleting all the datafiles and re-creating tablespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Next time, instead of "deleting everything", you can tell `imp` to ignore table creation error and still load the data by specifying the `IGNORE=y` option:

```
imp user/password file=MyExportFile.dmp IGNORE=y
```

There are few other considerations that you should make when importing into an existing schema, as outlined [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10825/exp_imp.htm#i1023662). Specifically, you may need to disable referential integrity constraints if they exists, otherwise some data may be rejected.

Comment: I tried this method today and it didn't work the way I wanted. Data won't be deleted from the new system if it has been deleted on the source since the last import. I also noticed that if your tables don't have a PK they will have a full duplicate copy of data added to them.